# GTK 2.0 cross compile for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

On my Ubuntu machine I am trying to compile GTK C files for Raspberry Pi.
When I do

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v
```

according to the tutorial *[Development Environment for the Raspberry Pi using a Cross Compiling Toolchain and Eclipse](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/)*, I should get:

```
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/dips/raspi_image/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
```

...

But I get:

```
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

But when I do

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -v
```

I get the correct path:

```
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/dips/raspi_image/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like there is a distro cross-compiler installed on the system.  It uses the same tuple, `arm-linux-gnueabihf`, but it is almost certainly ARMv7, not ARMv6 (i.e., it will work for the Pi 2 but not other models).  Sort of a dumb/ambiguous thing about that naming scheme.

The reason you don't have that issue with g++ is the C++ version of the compiler must be installed separately, and evidently it is not installed.

You can confirm this with `which arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.  You'll probably get:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

The problem goes back to this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/...
```

This adds that directory to the *end* of `$PATH`.  When the shell looks for something, it goes through the `$PATH` directories in order from left to right.  If you `echo $PATH` you'll notice `/usr/bin` is in there before your home directory.  That's bass ackwards.

Instead, use:

```
export PATH=$HOME/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/...:$PATH
```

With the full directory path, obviously.  The shell will now look there first, and `which` should show the right gcc.

I suggest you actually *don't* put that in `.bashrc`.  When you want to use that cross-compiler, just `export` on the command line and it will be effective for that shell and its children (i.e., not your entire log in session).  To make it easier, you can put it in a file somewhere and

```
source whatever.file
```

You probably want a file like that anyway also with at least

```
export PREFIX=$HOME/rpi/tools/install_path/
```

So that you can `./configure; make; make install` stuff and have it put somewhere that isn't `/usr/local`, where it may overwrite existing stuff and will not work.  This needs to exist of course:

```
mkdir $HOME/rpi/tools/install_path/
mkdir $HOME/rpi/tools/install_path/bin
mkdir $HOME/rpi/tools/install_path/lib
mkdir $HOME/rpi/tools/install_path/include
```

You only need to do that once.  This is the same path you should use for various `SYSROOT` variables; there might be other/different/better instructions regarding this for that cross-compiler, which I have not used.  The [sysroot](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/cross-compiling.html) is important to the compiler if you are building things with libraries you have built, which is presumably the case here.